# Problems in algorithm2e when superscript is in text mode

Tags: algorithm2e

How can I fix the issue with the words **Nuevo** and **Mejor**? They are appearing in math mode but they should appear in textmode:

[image]

Also, why does `\argmax_{\mathbf{x} \in \mathcal{X}}` appear next to arg max instead of below?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{arg\,max}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]

    \DontPrintSemicolon % Some LaTeX compilers require you to use \dontprintsemicolon instead

    \KwIn{.}
    \KwOut{.}
    %   \textit{Inicialización}:\\
    %   Aleatoriamente inicializar $b_{u}$ y $b_{i}$\\

    \For{$t = 1$ \text{hasta} $T$}{

        Ajustar $\Psi$ hasta $\mathcal{H}$\\ 
        $\mathbf{x}^{\text{\tiny Nuevo}} = \argmax_{\mathbf{x} \in \mathcal{X}} a(\Psi(\mathbf{x},\mathcal{D}), \mathcal{H})$\\
        Evaluar $b(\mathbf{x}^{\text{\tiny Nuevo}},\mathcal{D})$\\

        \If{$b(\mathbf{x}^{\text{\tiny Nuevo}},\mathcal{D}) < b(\mathbf{x}^{\text{\tiny Mejor}},\mathcal{D})$}{


            $\mathbf{x}^{\text{\tiny Mejor}}=\mathbf{x}^{\text{\tiny Nuevo}}$\\
            $\mathcal{H} = \mathcal{H} \cup (\mathbf{x}^{\text{\tiny Nuevo}},b(\mathbf{x}^{\text{\tiny Nuevo}},\mathcal{D})) $


        }

    }

\Return $\mathbf{x}^{\text{\tiny Mejor}}$

\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `\If` is exapanded, its first argument (the condition) is wrapped in an `\emph{...}` call such that the text occurs emphasized, i.e. usually in italics font. `\text` sets its argument in the current text font, which is italics in this context, so the superscript is printed like that.

As a rule of thumb, use `\text` in math mode only when you want to use actual explaining text. Parts of variables names shouldn't usually be mixed with text fonts. So as an alternative use `\mathrm` for printing the superscript. To also make the text smaller than normal superscripts, you can additionally set `\scriptscriptsize`, because `\tiny` doesn't work in math mode.

To remove code verbosity, I suggest to define new commands for those special variables:

```
\newcommand\xNuevo{\ensuremath{\mathbf{x}^{\scriptscriptstyle\mathrm{Nuevo}}}}
\newcommand\xMejor{\ensuremath{\mathbf{x}^{\scriptscriptstyle\mathrm{Mejor}}}}
```

and use them in your code:

```
\If{$b(\xNuevo,\mathcal{D}) < b(\xMejor,\mathcal{D})$}{...}
```

---

As for the second problem, operators in inline math mode (like between `$...$`) have their sub- and superscripts set next to them to reduce the height of the current line. If you want to force the scripts above and below, add `\limits` after the operator name:

```
\argmax\limits_{\mathbf{x} \in \mathcal{X}}
```

If you *always* want the scripts above/below, you can define `\argmax` as follows:

```
\newcommand\argmax{\mathop{\operatorname{arg\,max}}\limits}
```

Updated example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}
%\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{arg\,max}
\newcommand\argmax{\mathop{\operatorname{arg\,max}}\limits}

\newcommand\xNuevo{%
    \ensuremath{\mathbf{x}^{\scriptscriptstyle\mathrm{Nuevo}}}%
}
\newcommand\xMejor{%
    \ensuremath{\mathbf{x}^{\scriptscriptstyle\mathrm{Mejor}}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]

    \DontPrintSemicolon % Some LaTeX compilers require you to use \dontprintsemicolon instead

    \KwIn{.}
    \KwOut{.}
    %   \textit{Inicialización}:\\
    %   Aleatoriamente inicializar $b_{u}$ y $b_{i}$\\

    \For{$t = 1$ \text{hasta} $T$}{

        Ajustar $\Psi$ hasta $\mathcal{H}$\\ 
        $\mathbf{x}^{\text{\tiny Nuevo}} = \argmax\limits_{\mathbf{x} \in \mathcal{X}} a(\Psi(\mathbf{x},\mathcal{D}), \mathcal{H})$\\
        Evaluar $b(\mathbf{x}^{\text{\tiny Nuevo}},\mathcal{D})$\\

        \If{$b(\xNuevo,\mathcal{D}) < b(\xMejor,\mathcal{D})$}{


            $\mathbf{x}^{\text{\tiny Mejor}}=\mathbf{x}^{\text{\tiny Nuevo}}$\\
            $\mathcal{H} = \mathcal{H} \cup (\mathbf{x}^{\text{\tiny Nuevo}},b(\mathbf{x}^{\text{\tiny Nuevo}},\mathcal{D})) $


        }

    }

\Return $\mathbf{x}^{\text{\tiny Mejor}}$

\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Top notch explanation, thank you so much!